# failed to fetch volume file

Tags: linux, glusterfs

When my client try to connect gluster server it gives below error:

[glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1627:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-mgmt: failed to fetch volume file (key:gluster_vol_0)

My client is an  Amazon Linux instance located on Anazon EC2. 
I installed glusterfs-fuse like below:

```
sudo su -

#install glusterfs repo
wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/LATEST/EPEL.repo   /glusterfs-epel.repo
#fix it for amazon linux
sed -i 's/$releasever/6/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/glusterfs-epel.repo 

#install glusterfs
yum install -y glusterfs-fuse

#setup fstab
echo "hostname.example.com:/media-volume /mnt/glusterfs glusterfs defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab

#mount
mkdir -p /mnt/glusterfs
mount -a
```

Could you help me please.

Kind regards...

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. If I find a solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/482757/failed-to-fetch-volume-file

might help the one who still has this issue these days

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error (missing key) when installing Glusterfs-server 3.3.1 today. My resolution was to manually install the same version on the client side, as the repo offered me an older version than 3.3.1.

Atleast it fixed it in my case using Debian 6 as server and Ubuntu 12.04 as client.